# Word VBA - How to Trim a String down to just it's "text phrase"?

Tags: macos, vba, ms-word

I am using Word VBA in MS Word 2011 for Mac to process a set of DOCX's.

I have a string in my VBA Variable called STRING_VAR already.

I need to get rid of "n" paragraph breaks, line breaks etc. that exist before the phrase in my string. There are also "spaces" both before and after the alphanumeric phrase that I need to get rid of. "n" varies depending on which DOCX file I am running the VBA Macro on.

e.g. STRING_VAR is:

(CR)
(CR)
(CR)
The Cat Sat On The Mat (LF)

RESULT_VAR needs to be:
The Cat Sat On The Mat

How do I do this?  (Using the TRIM function in VBA only seems to get rid of the spaces.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
STRING_VAR = Replace(STRING_VAR, vbLf,"")
STRING_VAR = Replace(STRING_VAR, Chr(11),"") '<<< remove vertical tab
STRING_VAR = Trim(Replace(STRING_VAR, vbCr,""))
```

Comment: Mostly works but I'm having a problem with a LF character at the end of my STRING_VAR not getting removed.

Comment: @bibadia When I run MsgBox AscW(Right(STRING_VAR, 1)) in my code I get a result of "11" if this problem character exists after the text part of the string.   This problem character is entered on the Mac using the SHIFT+ENTER keystroke.

Comment: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/vertical-tab-male-symbol-mars-ascii-code-11.html

Comment: I can see that ASCII 11 is "Vertical Tab".  Is that the character that's entered on a Mac when you press the SHIFT+ENTER key?  Thanks for the new code.

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test that, but if the code removes it then you're good to go.  You should be able to extend this to deal with any other problem characters.

Comment: Yes, Shift-Enter inserts Ascii 11 on both Windows and Mac Word.